# QThread causing entire program to sleep in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

This is my first attempt at trying to subclass QThreads and use it in a program but I'm getting something kind of weird. I'm not sure if my constructor is wrong or something like that, but basically when I run my QThread the entire program sleeps (not just the thread) when the QThread is sleeping

For example, the provided code will print "Hello there" after 3 seconds which is how long the QThread is supposed to sleep for

How do I fix my code so that I can have my thread running in the background while the program is running

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import time

class MyThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        self.sleep(3)
        print("Slept for 3 seconds")


def main():
    qThread = MyThread()
    qThread.run()

    print("Hello there")

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `start` not `run`:

```
def main():
    qThread = MyThread()
    qThread.start()

    print("Hello there")
```

Since `run` is the [*starting point*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#run) for the thread (which exists in case you wanted to reuse the code not in a thread),

whilst `start` is the method to start the thread itself, so it will in turn call `run`

Answer (score -1):

To complete ptolemy0's answer, i can share you the code i'm using to practice on Qt:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QWidget, QApplication
import sys, time

class MyThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.sleep(3)
            print("Slept for 3 seconds")

class Main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(Main,self).__init__(parent)

        qThread = MyThread()
        qThread.start()

        i=0
        while True:

            print(i)
            i+=1
            time.sleep(1)



def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    example = Main()

    print("Hello there")
    sys.exit(app.exec())

main()
```

Hope it can help you!

Comment: `while True:` in the GUI? Can you resize your widget? I think that with your code the GUI will freeze

Comment: I use it as a starting point to see if everything is running in parallel but indeed it's maybe not optimized... but it's working for me!

Comment: It has nothing to do with optimization, your code does not work since it freezes the GUI.